# Broadcasting (two) vectors in Eigen C++

Tags: c++, eigen, broadcasting

Suppose I have an input ArrayXd of size 3:

```
P[1]                   
P[2]                 
P[3]
```

My required symmetric MatrixXd is of size [3,3]:

```
-P[1]*P[1]+P[1]   -P[2]*P[1]         -P[3]*P[1]  
-P[1]*P[2]        -P[2]*P[2]+P[2]    -P[3]*P[2]
-P[1]*P[3]        -P[2]*P[3]         -P[3]*P[3]+P[3]
```

Solution in pseudo code:

```
-1.0 * P.broadcast.rowwise() * P.broadcast.colwise() + diag(P)
```

Problem: 
The Eigen manual explains that you can broadcast a vector, but only in combination with a Matrix (or two-dimensional Array). How is it done with two vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for an outer-product which is nothing else than a standard matrix product:

```
-P * P.transpose() + P.asDiagonal()
```